# Wine network problem installing Photoshop

Tags: wireless, wine, internet

I need to install Photoshop CC 2017 via wine. When I turn off my Wifi or network, wine can't see that that I am disconnected from internet!

[image: wine network problem]

`sudo lshw -class network`:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 3a
   serial: f0:d5:bf:f0:d0:02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-45-generic firmware=21.302800.0 ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:128 memory:ef100000-ef101fff
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58d2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04b8:08a8 Seiko Epson Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d58 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: did you disconnect internet before starting wine?

Comment: What's your question? Bug reports are off topic but I can't vote to close questions with open bounties.

Comment: @Sithell: You're welcome to suggest an [edit] to the question to clarify what you think OP meant ask and what you'd like to know.